# How can I generate a barcode on iPhone and Android?

Tags: iphone, android, objective-c, ios

In my project I have to get the barcode type from its barcode number. Is there any framework or piece of sample code out there that can handle this on both iPhone and Android?

I have Googled around and found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at http://code.google.com/p/zxing/. This includes a barcode generator.